# WPF Setting Background Color In C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have done a fair bit of Googling on this since yesterday but haven't found much that makes sense.
I have a file which contains the settings for an app, which I think are being read properly, but the code to change my background colour may not be.

I am trying to change the colour used for the window background based on the information in the settings file file.

**Window Code**

```
<Window x:Class="WindowFrame.MainWindow" Name="WindowFrame"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="WindowFrame" 
    ResizeMode="NoResize" 
    ShowInTaskbar="False" 
    Topmost="True" 
    Focusable="False" 
    IsHitTestVisible="False" 
    AllowsTransparency="True" 
    WindowStyle="None" 
    Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidthKey}}" 
    Height="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeightKey}}" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    Background="#7FAC0000" 
    WindowState="Maximized">
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Dusk_for_Windows
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    /// 
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index, int newStyle);

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "settings.txt");
            string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            string[] contentArray = fileContent.Split(':');
            string contentColor;
            string contentIntensity;

            for (int i = 0; i < contentArray.Length; i++)
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        {
                            if (contentArray[i].ToLower().Contains("color: "))
                            {
                                contentColor = contentArray[i].Replace("title: ", "");

                                if(contentColor == "light")
                                {
                                    BrushConverter bc = new BrushConverter();
                                    Brush brush = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#C7DFFC");
                                    brush.Freeze();
                                    WindowFrame.Background = brush;
                                }
                            }

                            if (contentArray[i].ToLower().Contains("intensity: "))
                            {
                                contentIntensity = contentArray[i].Replace("intensity: ", "");
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
        }

        public static class WindowsServices
        {
            const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x00000020;
            const int GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20);

            public static void SetWindowExTransparent(IntPtr hwnd)
            {
                var extendedStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
                SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyle | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
            var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
            WindowsServices.SetWindowExTransparent(hwnd);
        }
    }
}
```

I am fairly certain the code between lines 42 and 65 is in fact reading the file correctly, but if it isn't, please let me know.

The file being read looks like this:

```
color: light
intensity: 1
```

Comment: Try to set bkg color of your Grid like `MyGrid.Background = brush;` , and try to remove extra attributes from `<Window>` tag.

Comment: Did you step through and make sure that your code is reaching inside all those if statements? Also, since you're using just WPF you dont technically need `WindowFrame`. `this` will suffice or even just `Background = brush;` since you're inside the code-behind for the window you have there.

Comment: Don't use settings text file, use a real settings file and you can bind directly to the values in xaml with converters if you want. But the proper way to do themes would be to actually use themes...

Comment: @K.Briggs : seems that you fixed your yesterday's error, why don't you go to yesterday question and mark it as answered for the sake of helping this community, thx.